# html5 audio: play sounds "instantly" on ipad when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

was writing some script similar to piano, thats mean it should play sounds INSTANTLY when u tap/touch/click the button.

But the problem is that, its seems like it takes time ( which relatively alot ) to play each sounds once tap.

as it looks more like streaming which takes times to load :/

Is there any other approach I can use to achieve this ?

Thanks :D , (*for reading at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this after `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
yourAudioElement.play();
setTimeout(function(){
 yourAudioElement.pause();
},1);
```

This will force iOS browser to cache the resources

Comment: The purpose of disabling preloading is to save people their limited monthly bandwidth consumption. We don't need people going around bypassing this so they can quietly preload some massive file while we read a webpage. So -1.

Comment: There are two options. **preload and play it without delay** or **do not preload and wait for load**. You can't have both. If you want the media plays without lag you have to load it. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: My comment is for those of us with a 500MB (or so) data plan and people like you offer up solutions to preload video/audio. Why would I want people to preload content on my cell phone, that is stupid.

Comment: Agree to Mohsen i dont care qbout data plan. I'll try this code and will be back to rate the answer. Thank You :D

Answer (score 3):

Preloading `<audio>` and `<video>` on iOS devices is disabled to save bandwidth.

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

Source: [Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1)

Comment: i know that, ( had been googling alot ) thats why im looking for somekind of hack another way to play sounds. Thanks for the info again anyway :D